# How to show a HTML page at the bottom right corner instead of in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

What I want to do is to show the content of a HTML page at the bottom right corner of a page through my js script like below

[image]

In order to accomplish this, I do not want to put a div in the page and then the page to be appeared in it, BUT with somehow to place it there alternatively.

The goal is to edit nothing from the page, all the magic must be done through the .js file.

So for now what I have is this :

```
<div id="topBar"> <a href ="#" onclick="load_home()"> HOME </a> </div>
<div id ="content"> </div>
<script>
function load_home()
{
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
}
</script>
```

but it loads the page where I place the div, not overlay.

How to do this?

Comment: You need to create an `iframe` if you want to display content from another html page. The `iframe` will be positioned at the bottom right of the page

Comment: @RaraituL I described that I dont want to edit the page, and the code posted loads html from another domain without iframe.

Comment: You want the content of the page being added on your page without you manually adding it? or you want the content to appear but without modifying the html content of your page?

Comment: is [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) what you need?

Comment: @RaraituL More important for now is to show the content of the external file in my page without modifying the html content of my page for this to appear at the bottom right corner.

Comment: @XAlloumokkelos: If you want to do this **without** modifying the html content of your page, you have to use an `iframe` for this. Using `AJAX` will simply append the content to your page

Answer (score 0):

If JQuery is ok with you, then you can have a look at the following options
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-notify/

http://notifyjs.com/ (This one has same effect like the one described in above image)

You can load the html page via AJAX and then render it into the DIVs created using any of the above plugin.

For cross domains, you may have to try out following approach
http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html

Comment: Oh great links, thank you. Are these can be done with just Javascript?

Comment: Yes @Xalloumokkelos you can surely do this with the JavaScript.